# How to add custom icon and group indicator to ExpandableListview android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

[image]I am using `ExpandableListview` with custom `group indicator`.
I am successful in this 
But ,Now there is a situation where I need both `custom icon` on left and `group indicator` on right 
How do I achieve this .

Please suggest me how do I alter my adapter class

list_group.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="#FEFFFF">





    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

          <ImageView android:id="@+id/shape_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/off"     
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:text="Group Header"
        android:textColor="#272727"
        android:textSize="17dp" />



    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/listview_expander_group"
     android:contentDescription="expand image"
    android:id="@+id/explist_indicator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

ExpandableListAdapter.java

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private static final int[] EMPTY_STATE_SET = {};
    private static final int[] GROUP_EXPANDED_STATE_SET =
            {android.R.attr.state_expanded};
    private static final int[][] GROUP_STATE_SETS = {
        EMPTY_STATE_SET, // 0
        GROUP_EXPANDED_STATE_SET // 1
    };
    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child, null);
        }

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_child_chkbox);




        txtTitle.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        Log.e("groupPosition", "kargr "+groupPosition);

            return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .size();


    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);              

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        View ind = convertView.findViewById( R.id.explist_indicator);
        if( ind != null ) {
            ImageView indicator = (ImageView)ind;
            if( getChildrenCount( groupPosition ) == 0 ) {
                indicator.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
            } else {
                indicator.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                int stateSetIndex = ( isExpanded ? 1 : 0) ;
                Drawable drawable = indicator.getDrawable();
                drawable.setState(GROUP_STATE_SETS[stateSetIndex]);
            }
        }


        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks correct to me. Isn't it working ?

Comment: the correct, but only for " group indicator " ,.Not for custom icon on left and group indicator on right ...